# indexページに横並びで掲載する方法を教えてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css

お世話になります。rails 初心者です。rails 4 でレシピアプリを作成中です。

indexページに３製品横並びにmodelに保存された内容を掲載したいのですが、
どのようにアレンジすればよいのでしょうか。

現在、.each のloop しかわからず、縦並びになってしまいます。

<現在のコード：index.html.erb>

```
 <% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
        <%=link_to recipe do%>
          <%= image_tag recipe.image.url (:thumb)  %>
        <% end %>
        <h2><%=link_to recipe.title,recipe %></2>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/104987

Answer (score 1):

色んな方法があると思いますが、flexboxを使ったサンプルを掲示しておきます。

https://codepen.io/itmammoth/pen/mpewWa

こんな感じのhtmlが出力されるようerbを編集してください。
余白や位置揃えなどその他諸々は[flexbox](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=flexbox)を検索して調べてみてください。

Answer (score 0):

Hタグは**見出し**なので、希望のレイアウトの様に横一列に並べたい要素に使うことがそもそも適切でない気がします。
テーブルを組んで「画像の列」「料理名の列」をそれぞれ順に出力するようには出来ないでしょうか。

Comment: <% @recipes.each_slice(3) do |recipes| %>アドバイス頂いた内容もメモし、今後の参考に致します。ありがとうございます